# Using submit with JS does not pass DATA

Tags: javascript, submit-button

I'm using (function clicado()):

```
document.getElementById('enviar').click();
```

html:

```
<a href="#" id="pagar" onclick="clickado();"></a><input type='submit' id='enviar'></div>
```

I'm trying to pass data to PHP, but a problem is happening, the data simply does not pass.

Have you tried using `submit();` and also does not work.

Whhen I click in , work fine, but when I do the JS "clicking for me" ...

I hope the question is not superficial, basically my problem is to pass the data.

Here is the URL:
http://as4.com.br/gateway/index.php

Here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" id="formcompra" name="formcompra">
    <input id="cvv" name='cvv'>
        <div class="pagar" ><a href="#" id="pagar" onclick="clickado();"></a><input type='submit' id='enviar'></div>

</form>
```

I really want to submit this form with JS.

Comment: there are no value attribs or type addribs on your input tags. What should be passed it the name=value pair.

Comment: all inputs have type='text'...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link you provided, the name of your form is `formcompra`. If you call `document.formcompra.submit()` this will submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#enviar").click(function(){
        $("#formcompra").submit();
});
```

try something like this

Comment: try removing the onclick event inline.